# Module that returns function based on bool not returning correct function

Tags: node.js

I am using [this library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-ffprobe) to control ffprobe in my script. To avoid creating more child processes in my script I need to use the synchronous version of the command from the library. According to the documentation it should be as easy as setting `probe.SYNC = true`.

However, regardless of the value of `probe.SYNC` calling the probe function always uses `doProbe` instead of using `doProbeSync`.

```js
// index.js
import probe from 'node-ffprobe';

probe.SYNC = true;

let data = probe('video.mp4'); // Incorrectly calls doProbe()

// node-ffprobe.js
module.exports = (function () {
    function doProbeSync(file) {
        ...
    }

    function doProbe(file) {
        ...
    }

    return module.exports.SYNC ? doProbeSync : doProbe
})()
```

The only reason I think of that this might not be working is because my script is written with ES6 syntax, but I am not sure how that would impact this.

How can I get the node-ffprobe library to use `doProbeSync`?

Comment: write your code in commonJS or moduels. both together just leads to confusion

Comment: This is not my module